# White spaces in Newsletter

Tags: html, css, newsletter

I m working over an newsletter and facing a problem of white spacing in windows live mail and some images are missing in outlook2007. I have used these image as html attribute background and using  tag as well.

In which most of the images used as background(Not CSS background) are not showing in outlook2007.

Can anyone help me please.

Comment: Campaign monitor's guide to CSS support in emails - http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are the images hardlinks to the files (http://www.yoursite.com/yourfile.jpg) and are you sure your just not clicking the button to allow images? most modern email clients prevent HTML Email images from loading until you explicitly click to allow them. Also, background images DO NOT work in HTML emails.

Comment: yes, Email clients are preventing the loading of images and i have to click on allow images. That means there is no solution for using background images?